# Ошибка: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded на Linux (C++)

Tags: c++, mysql, база-данных, qt, qsqldatabase

В попытках поставить драйвер, перерыл пол-интернета.
В качестве БД использую MySql, но обертка поверх нее XAMPP.

Нашел что нужно самостоятельно ставить плагин, но по адресу `Qt/5.12.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers` имею лишь:

> libqsqlite.so      libqsqlodbc.so    libqsqlpsql.so
>   libqsqlite.so.debug  libqsqlodbc.so.debug  libqsqlpsql.so.debug

.cpp file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setDatabaseName("Testbase");
    db.setUserName("Cy");
    db.setPassword("xxxx");
    if( db.open() )
    {
        qDebug() << "Connected!";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to connect.";
        return 0;
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available
>   drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Comment: собирать надо qt из исходников и при конфигурации указать нужные драйвера

Comment: Я скачал готовую сборку с оф. сайта QT
И что мне, удалять и ставить по-новой?

Comment: да можно поставить в другое место, например в Qt5/..., если ок, то старую удалить, он не привязан строго к пути

Comment: Не надо пересобирать Qt, драйвер для MySql это плагин и надо просто собрать его и положить в нужную папочку, вот тут написано как https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494435/4711135

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. Собирать драйвер mysql вручную из исходников (читайте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html). Скомпилированные драйвера для mysql interbase/firebird в официальной сборке никогда(!) не идут (чтобы не попадать под их лицензии)
2. Используйте odbc для соединения с mysql